# Accessing object members in PHP

Tags: php, object

I'm calling a WCF service in PHP which returns me this thing: (The service I'm calling returns a C# struct)

```
object(stdClass)#70 (1) {
  ["SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult"]=>
    object(stdClass)#149 (5) {
      ["result"]=>
        bool(true)
      ["strAccountExec"]=>
        NULL
      ["strAccountId"]=>
        string(36) "bd346671-88ca-4966-971a-9dd499c7a689"
      ["strContactId"]=>
        string(36) "06a8808d-ed66-42f9-a821-00358213bb94"
      ["strOpportunityId"]=>
        string(36) "d4845fd0-18fb-4a40-8424-904866cb471e"
    }
}
```

Question is, how do I access the values? Those values are the true boolean and three guids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `result`

```
$var->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult->result;
```

To get the `guid`s

```
$var->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult->strAccountId
$var->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult->strContactId
$var->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult->strOpportunityId
```

Answer (score 1):

make link for easyer use in future,

```
$oResult = &$oStruct->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult;
```

then go with

```
echo $oResult->strAccountId;
```

to get strAccountId value

Answer (score 0):

You could do (assuming `$returnedObject` is the returned object)

```
$strOpportunityId = $returnedObject
                                ->SiteInterop_CreateContactAndOpportunityResult
                                ->strOpportunityId
```